# Values not passing from html form to Javascript, variables logging undefined, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to make a small site for class that will changes maps based on drop down selection. The first map pops up fine because I have the lat and long values hard coded, but when you use the drop down box, the values come back undefined. I dont think it's being passed correctly and I can't figure out why.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <link href ='style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[hidden]"></script>

    <title>Geolocation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="formArea">
        <form>
            <h1>Famous Cities</h1>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Cities</label>
                <select id="selectedCity" name="selectedCity">
                    <option value='None'>Please select a city from the dropdown</option>
                    <option value='ITA'>Rome, Italy</option>
                    <option value='FRA'>Paris, France</option>
                    <option value='USA'>New York, USA</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JS file is below

```
var map;

function initMap() {
        var mapDisplay = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7484,-73.9857),
        zoom: 8
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapDisplay, mapOptions);

        console.log('now exiting initMap');
}


var coordsLat = {
    'ITA':41.9028,
    'FRA':48.8566,
    'USA':40.7128,
};

var coordsLng = {
    'ITA': 12.4964,
    'FRA': 2.3522,
    'USA': -74.0060
};

function changeSelection(loc) {
    var lac = coordsLat[loc];
    var lgc = coordsLng[loc];
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lac, lgc));
    console.log('selection changed')
    console.log('new coordinates are now: ' + lac +" : " + lgc);
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('load', function(){
    initMap();
    $("#selectedCity").change(changeSelection);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so because you pass an Event object to the `changeSelection` method. You need to pass a value instead:

```
$("#selectedCity").change(function() {
  changeSelection($(this).val());
});
```

This would work because jQuery sets `this` within the handler's callback to a DOM element. Per [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element):

> Whenever you call jQuery's .each() method or one of its event methods
>   on a jQuery collection, the context of the callback function — this —
>   is set to a DOM element.

Comment: ah works perfectly. Took me a little bit to understand what you meant, but If i'm understanding correctly, on mine, changeSelection was just passing in the element, but not the value, so this refers to this object and val pulls the actual value? crude explanation but its the best way I can explain lol

Comment: @Jordan I made a little update... The Event object had been passed in that case, see [the doc](https://api.jquery.com/change/): "handler Type: Function( Event eventObject )"

Answer (score 0):

you are calling

```
$("#selectedCity").change(changeSelection);
```

while your function changeSelection needs a parameter

```
function changeSelection(loc) { ... }
```

you probably want to get the value of the select, therefore I would recommend:

```
$("#selectedCity").change(function({changeSelection($("#selectedCity").options[$("#selectedCity").selectedIndex].value);});
```